# Desktop drive mount icons aren't files or symlinks in '~/Desktop' directory?

Tags: linux-mint, partition

**BACKSTORY/INTRO:**

I recently installed Linux Mint 18 Sarah because I was essentially forced to, but I already love linux. When I was doing my reading I realized that I would have to partition my drive and stick Linux in its own partition. This meant, or so I thought, that I wouldn't be able to access files in my Windows OS as that would be a different partition. However, when I was playing around making directories and such, I noticed that my Windows 8 C drive was not only accessible, but also considered removable media like a USB. I then went through my C drive looking at text files bc I was confused as to why I could see them. A few hours later after coming back from being in Windows, my C drive and another drive I've never seen before were on my desktop, however, when I used `cd Desktop` and then `ls` neither drive was visible in the Desktop directory. When I'm in Windows I can't see Linux Mint at all.

**QUESTION:**

a) How was I able to access files from another partition and then magically have them be on my Desktop while not being in my Desktop?

b) Did I screw something up when I installed?

Beyond this I haven't had any real issues with bugs so far. Linux is cool.

**EDIT:**
I've asked/answered questions on other Stackexchange sites and each seems to have a preference for formatting and how you ask a question. Please let me if there are any issues with formatting or how I've asked my question.

Comment: Linux comes with the ability to mount Windows partitions. Windows does not come with a similar ability vis-a-vis Linux.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Okay. So I didn't screw up, it's just a perk of Linux. That is beyond convenient. Fricking awesome.

Comment: See also [3 Ways to Access Your Linux Partitions From Windows](http://www.howtogeek.com/112888/3-ways-to-access-your-linux-partitions-from-windows/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a. *Linux Mint*'s *GUI* desktop *includes* `~/Desktop`, but 
the *GUI* desktop <> `~/Desktop`.  Rather those removable media icons are put there by some service util... *which* util it is varies between desktop environments.  If one was to stop or `kill` this service util,  the media icons would vanish, or at least vanish until the service util was restarted.

b. No you didn't screw something up.  The service util doesn't effect `~/Desktop`, just the *GUI*.

Comment: oh, so some service dropped them onto the GUI (I dont remember my DE, I'll check later.), but just because they are there doesn't mean that they would be in the `~/Desktop`? That's different from windows for sure.